# Monty Hall problem: Is the probability to win by switching $2/3$ even if we don't know the host's behavior?

Tags: probability, statistics, monty-hall

**Preview**

Some of the confusion with the Monty Hall problem comes because it is not always stated that the host must always reveal a goat from the two doors that the player did not pick and offer the switch. Generally, it is only said that he knows the locations of the contents, and did the revelation this time. This leaves the possible interpretation that he only did it because the contestant had chosen the winner door, and the host is trying to make him change so he loses.

Now, there are those who argue that since it is established that he knows the locations of the contents, then it is not necessary to say that he always executes that action as a protocol, but it is enough to know that he did it this time, because for every possible extra behavior, there is always a counterpart that cancels it out and makes the probabilities $2/3$ again.

It's a reasoning of symmetry similar to the one used to argue that the chances that the host opens any of the other two doors are $1/2$ when the player has picked the winner option, despite nothing in the rules state that he must choose one of them at random. Someone could argue that he could have the preference of always opening the lowest numbered one of those that are available for him, but others could also argue that he could have the opposite preference of always opening the highest numbered one. That is, any argument that could be said about one door could also be said about the other, so the average of all possible preferences is that he is $1/2$ likely to reveal each door.

This symmetry seems to be accepted despite the set of all the possible preferences are not formally described.

**Question**

In the same way, despite for some of the host's behaviors it could be better to switch and for others not, can we apply a reasoning of symmetry similar to the described above to say that, when we don't know the current behavior, the average of all possible ones is $2/3$ chance of success by switching?

Can we be sure that for any possible behavior we can find an oppposite one such that, when combining the two, the probability to win by switching inside the group is always $2/3$? (And also that the relation will always be One-to-One, because if it isn't, we can't make the cancellation).

**Example**

Suppose that the only three possible behaviors were:

$A)$ He always opens a goat door regardless of what the player picked.

$B)$ He only opens a goat door when the player has picked a goat door.

$C)$ He only opens a goat door when the player has picked the car door.

There may be reasons to argue that cases $B)$ and $C)$ don't need to be equally likely, but if we bypass that part for now and assume for simplicity that they are in fact equally likely, then the overall probability to win by switching is $2/3$, because inside the group of $B)$ and $C)$, the opportunity would only be offered $2/3$ of the times that we are in case $B)$, and $1/3$ of the times that we are in case $C)$, meaning that switching ends up winning $2/3$ of the combined opportunities. When we join it with the proportion of case $A)$, that is also $2/3$ as has been discussed several times, the overall average remains $2/3$.

This does not need that the three possible behaviors are equally likely, as long as the pair of opposite behaviors $B)$ and $C)$ are.

**Possible conterarguments**

My concern is if for each possible behavior it will always be possible to find an opposite one that is equally likely to it. I was thinking about these two, that may seem opposite to each other because the door to reveal is never the same, but the probability inside the combined group is not $2/3$ but $1/2$:

$D)$ The host always tries to reveal the lowest numbered option of those that the player did not pick, but if it has not a goat, he does not do anything and the game ends.

$E)$ The host always tries to reveal the highest numbered option of those that the player did not pick, but if it has not a goat, he does not do anything and the game ends.

The probability to win by switching inside that group is $1/2$ because the opportunity would be offered everytime that the player has picked the car $(1/3)$, but half of the times that the player has picked a goat $(1/2 * 2/3 = 1/3)$, so each strategy would be equally likely.

If the probability of being in that group is greater than zero, then it would lower the average $2/3$ that the other possibilities combined have.

But maybe I'm doing it wrong when grouping those two behaviors. Maybe the opposite of $D)$ shouldn't be $E)$ but any other one.

And as someone pointed out in the comments, another possible protocol that seems to not have a counterpart is:

$F)$ He opens a door the player didn’t choose at random and if it has a goat, he offers the chance to switch to the other unopened door.

Although this protocol would not make use of the host's knowledge of the locations, so it could be said that it shouldn't be taken into consideration. But however unreasonable it may be, it has a chance to exist.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  What point are you trying to make?  Obviously, if you change the rules, you might change the posterior probabilities.

Comment: This is well known: your choice of action depends crucially on the host's behaviour. In the real TV show, the host always offers you the option to change your selection, so you should always switch. But unless you know this fact, you really can't tell what your best course of action is.

Comment: Just to be clear:  there isn't anything magical about $\frac 23$.  In the variant where Monty has no idea where the prize is and just opens an unselected door randomly (with the game ending should he inadvertently reveal the prize), then there is no advantage to switching.  The advantage in the standard variant derives entirely from his knowledge, if he has no knowledge, there is no advantage.  Other variants are possible, it all depends on a clear description of the rules.

Comment: @lulu My point is: If we consider all possible behaviors of the host once we state that he knows the locations, can we say the overall probabilities are still 2/3? We know that for some behaviors the result could be one, and for others, the result could be any other different. But if we take all those that we can imagine and average them, is the result 2/3, or maybe there is a pair of behaviors that cannot cancel out, making the average different?

Comment: This is very vague.  "All possible behaviors " is hopeless.  You need a rule set,  and it's fine if the rules are defined probabilistically but you still need the rules.

Comment: @TonyK Speaking of the *real* show: “I never did it that way on the show.” https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=c1BSkquWkDo

Comment: Consider the behavior “open a door the player didn’t choose at random and if it has a goat, offer the chance to switch to the other unopened door.” What behavior do you pair that with to balance it?

Comment: @lulu Ok, but then this problem is similar to Bertrand paradox, isn't it? Because the domain of possibilities is infinite and many different set of rules could be defined, each one leading to different results

Comment: @DavidK Possibly there is no pair to that behavior, and it may be a counterexample to the aseveration that the probabilities are 2/3 on average.

Comment: I don't see the point here. Bertrand isn't a paradox, and neither is this.  In both situations, you need to specify the rules and if you don't the problem is not well defined.  Bertrand is somewhat more subtle in that, at least at first, it seems like all "natural" methods to define the probability situation should give the same result, but they don't.  Here, I don't see any reason at all why one would expect different rules to give the same result.  It seems clear that they don't.

Comment: Without knowing what Monty Hall does there is no optimal strategy (switching or not switching). If Monty Hall allows the switch only if you chose the door with the car , then switching NEVER wins.

Comment: @Peter I mentioned that behavior in the question. I edited it and divided it in sections, hoping it is clearer what I am trying to say.